# Do we know of any literature before Greek philosophy that discusses the properties of a living thing?

Tags: philosophy

I have been reading up on the first written works of literature leading up to philosophy as we understand it today. I am having a hard time to establish a clear time-line which leads up to the discussion on the properties of life, that is, what makes something living as opposed to non-living.

Being a student of computer science this is far out of my field of expertise. However, from preliminary research, the first works I came across is of course the Epic of Gilgamesh. The only part that sort of fits is where the man searches for the secret to eternal life. After that I am more or less lost since the next obvious option appears to be Akkadian literature but none of it seems to fit.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Full Disclosure:
I am including this in an assignment where I need to discuss the origin of the term 'life'. I thought a historical perspective might be illuminating for the reader.

Comment: To make it a little easier for people to find you material that predates Greek philosophy, could you edit into your question exactly which Greek philosophical material you are trying to predate?